# Represent the English statement into Quantifiers

Tags: predicate, quantifiers

Here is a statement

`C(x): x has a cat  D(x): x has a dog   F(x): x has a Ferret`
represent using quantifiers and logical connectives. Under the domain "all students in your class"

1) No student in your class has a cat, a dog or a ferret.

2) For each of the three animals, there is a student in your class who has one of these animals as a pet.

Can someone provide an answer for this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) ∀x (~C(x) ^ ~D(x) ^ ~F(x))

2) (∃xC(x)) ^ (∃xD(x)) ^ (∃xF(x))